# How to remove rows with NAs in a specific column but only if they have a duplicate in another column?

Tags: r

So I have this data frame, in which some rows are duplicated in the "Species" column, and some aren't.
There are NAs in all types of rows, both duplicated and not duplicated.

```
Species            |  A  |  B  |  
--------------------------------
Tilapia guineensis |  1  |  10 |  
Tilapia guineensis |  1  |  NA |   
Tilapia zillii     |  3  |  23 |  
Tilapia zillii     |  3  |  NA |  
Eutrigla gurnardus | 18  |  4  |
Caramila artida    |  9  |  NA |  
Sprattus sprattus  |  7  |  6  |
Spalili burcant    | 11  |  NA |
```

I want to remove that rows that have NAs in the B column, but only if they belong to a duplicate row.
My output would be something like this:

```
Species            |  A  |  B  |  
--------------------------------
Tilapia guineensis |  1  |  10 |    
Tilapia zillii     |  3  |  23 |    
Eutrigla gurnardus | 18  |  4  |
Caramila artida    |  9  |  NA |  
Sprattus sprattus  |  7  |  6  |
Spalili burcant    | 11  |  NA |
```

Basically, if a row is duplicated in the Species column and has a NA in the B column, I want to remove that row with the NA. However, if a row is unique in the Species column, I want to keep it even if it has NA.

Sorry if I'm being confusing, thanks in advance.

Reproducible data format:

```
df <- read.csv(text="
Species,A,B
Tilapia guineensis,1,10
Tilapia guineensis,1,NA
Tilapia zillii,3,23
Tilapia zillii,3,NA
Eutrigla gurnardus,18,4
Caramila artida,9,NA
Sprattus sprattus,7,6
Spalili burcant,11,NA")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select a row if there is only 1 row for the `Species` or if it is not an `NA` value.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Species) %>% filter(n() == 1 | !is.na(B))

#  Species                A     B
#  <chr>              <int> <int>
#1 Tilapia guineensis     1    10
#2 Tilapia zillii         3    23
#3 Eutrigla gurnardus    18     4
#4 Caramila artida        9    NA
#5 Sprattus sprattus      7     6
#6 Spalili burcant       11    NA
```

You can also write the same logic in base R and `data.table` :

```
#Base R
subset(df, ave(!is.na(B), Species, FUN = function(x) length(x) == 1 | x))

#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[.N == 1 | !is.na(B)], Species]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Species = c("Tilapia guineensis", "Tilapia guineensis", 
"Tilapia zillii", "Tilapia zillii", "Eutrigla gurnardus", "Caramila artida", 
"Sprattus sprattus", "Spalili burcant"), A = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
18L, 9L, 7L, 11L), B = c(10L, NA, 23L, NA, 4L, NA, 6L, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you can avoid using any grouping logic, and get the result in a single pass:

```
df[!(duplicated(df$Species) & is.na(df$B)),]
#             Species  A  B
#1 Tilapia guineensis  1 10
#3     Tilapia zillii  3 23
#5 Eutrigla gurnardus 18  4
#6    Caramila artida  9 NA
#7  Sprattus sprattus  7  6
#8    Spalili burcant 11 NA
```